# vb.net activated fires multiple times

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to update a database based on the form that is currently activated.  I had originally decided to use the GotFocus event.  However I now understand that will not work as the form has controls on it.  So I then thought I wouls use the activated event.  This works but seems to fire multiple times.  I put in the following code:

```
Private Sub frmNewTicket_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    MsgBox("Form Activated")
End Sub
```

I select the form and make it activated and the message box appears about 15 times.

Why does it do this?  How should I handle this.  I only want my code to execute once when the form is activated.

NOTE:  There are several forms that the users will be changing between, incuding forms from other applications.

Comment: From your question I derive, that you want to do "something" once for an active form? Perhaps the event LOAD or FORMCLOSING is what you are looking for. Load is executed just before the form is displayed the first time, not yet visible by the user. FormClosing is executed when the user (or the code) decides to close the window, still visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you click `OK` on the messagebox, the form regains the focus and is activated again.

Put a static `Boolean` value in your `frmNewTicket_Activated` like someone has posted [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showpost.php?p=1615616&postcount=2):

```
Static HasRan As Boolean=False
If Not HasRan Then
    HasRan=True
    'put code here
End If
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.  I tried this but this made no difference.

To be honest, I don't understand why it would either.  Everytime the event fires HasRan will be set to False and so will be false when it is tested further down the code.

If I move the declaration of HasRan elsewhere then it will only fire once and once only.

I guess I must be missing something there as I don't understand how it would work.


But you have helped solve the problem anyway.  I was using the msgbox just to test that it was firing.  I have removed the message box and it is working as desired.

Thanks

Comment: @Stephen when you give a static variable an initial value like that, it is only assigned the first time the `_Activated` method is run, not each time.  I'm glad you got it to work as you wanted it.  To get it to work this way might have taken a bit of tweaking, as what happens after the form is activated will matter.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are wanting to do something everytime your form gets activated. The `Form` `Activated` event will work fine as long as what you are doing doesn't pull focus from the `Form` which will then trigger another `Activation` event when the Form gets focus again. Try using something other than a `MessageBox` for testing like `Beep` or changing the Form's Color